# Spring Security + Spring-Boot Testing Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test, spring-security-test

I'm trying to test the home controller

```
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
String home() {
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

I'm using spring security using as username "user" and test as password by default but @PreAuthorize is not working

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "user", password = "test", roles = "ADMIN")
    public void home() throws Exception {
        String body = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/", String.class);
        assertThat(body).isEqualTo("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

The result

**Expected result:**

> <"[Hello World!]">

**Actual result:**

> <"{"timestamp":1501100448216,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full
>   authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/"}]">

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are invoking a real controller so using `@WithMockUser` is pretty much useless here. That would only work if you would directly call the `home()` method on the controller. Assuming you have basic authentication setup for login you should send the credentials with your request. Also `@PreAuthorize` on your test case won't achieve anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following to your test class:

```
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, listeners = {
        WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
```

And the following dependency if you don't have it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Spring security require an extra listener that is not present in tests by default so you need to tell spring to add it by specifing the `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation in `merge` mode so it will merge the current listed listeners with the listeners you want to add - in this case `WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work i'm receiving the same result :/

Comment: Try also to add `ROLE_ADMIN` to the `roles` in `@WithMockUser`. Spring security by default check for the prefix `ROLE` (but in `@PreAuthorize` keep it as `ADMIN`)